# Disconnect wires from relay terminals

Tags: relay

How can I disconnect the terminals from the relay on the circuit board below? The two terminals are in blue and black in the center of the image. The service manual simply says to disconnect them, but these terminals cannot simply be pulled out and removed. I'm assuming I need some type of tool to do this correctly, but I have not worked with this kind of relay before.

[image: circuit board with relay connection]

Comment: Looks like a common spade-connect. Just pull - if the connection wont seperate, use pliers within "reasonable" force-boundaries. Please do not grab the wire with the pliers. Grab it below the crimp connection (where the cable isolation is crimped) and "leaver" it out.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I would post this as the answer.

Comment: Look closely for a latching tab (can't tell from photo.)  Some spade connectors can have a little locking metal "nub" which needs pressed to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Many of these 1/4" spade connectors have a little spring tab formed into the connector, that partially engages a hole in the spade. This increases the retention force, against vibration and inadvertent disconnection.

If the tab only increases the force, then pulling harder (than you expect) will separate the terminals.

If the tab positively engages with the hole, then brute force alone won't do it, and you have to depress the tab before you can separate the terminals. Sometimes you can do this by pressing blindly in the middle of the connector. Sometimes you have to strip off the insulation to see what you're doing, and target the tab with a small screwdriver.

Comment: I pulled harder than I thought would be necessary and I was concerned that any further force would cause damage but maybe I just need to go for it. I'll check more closely for a tab.